# Is there an easier way to integrate $\int \frac{d\, x}{\sin^2{x}}$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

So, hey. 
I've made it like this: $ \tan{\frac{x}{2}} = t, x=2\arctan{t}, d\, x =\frac{2t\,d\,t}{1+t^2}$, therefore $\int\frac{d\, x}{\sin^2{x}} = \int\frac{1+t^2}{2t^2}d\,t$, which gives us $\frac{t^2-1}{2t}+ C$...
And then I had to make some truly unevident transformations in order to conclude that it was  just $(-\cot{x} +C)$

Tangent half-angle substitution seems a little...excessive here. Any tips to make it in a simpler way?

And, no, I have to prove that $\int \frac{d\, x}{\sin^2{x}}$ is $-\cot{x} +C$, and not just tell "Well, okay, $(-\cot{x})'=\frac{1}{\sin^2{x}}$, that's why $\int \frac{d\, x}{\sin^2{x}}= -\cot{x} +C$

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\int\csc ^2x=-\cot x+c$, that's a basic result!

Comment: I have to prove that, as I've already said in my question.

Comment: Why you're allergic to differentiating?

Comment: What @Aditya suggests is a perfectly valid method of proof. Make an ansatz and then verify it.

Comment: Nothing personal, it's just my task.
Once again, I'm not allowed to prove that by differentiating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it so badly, then:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^2x}=\int\frac{\sec^2xdx}{\tan^2x}=\int\frac{d(\tan x)}{\tan^2x}=-\frac1{\tan x}+c=-\cot x+c$$

Comment: Many thanks, that's what I've been looking for.

Comment: @Lebesgue if that's the case, accept it to show that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int dx\, \frac{1}{\sin^2 x} = \int dx\, \frac{\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}{\sin^2 x} = \int dx\, -\frac{ \cos x \sin' x - \sin x \cos'x}{\sin^2 x}=\int \frac{d}{dx}\left( -\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \right) = -\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}.
$$
The third equality is from the quotient rule.